# Reordering column names

Tags: r

I have a similar problem in two scenarios.

Scenario 1: dataframe with identical column names with two groups with no particular order. 
ALL|ALL|AML|ALL|AML|AML|AML|ALL

Scenario 2: dataframe column names with numeric suffixes.
ALL, ALL.1, ALL.2, AML.1, AML.2, ...this has double digit numbers too. If I order this in ascending order, it becomes ALL.1, ALL.10, ALL.11

I wish to group all ALLs first and the followed by AMLs. How can I achieve this in both scenarios?

Comment: Names that aren't unique are next to useless in a data.frame. Probably best to call `make.unique` before doing anything else. All told, perhaps `library(purrr); names(df) <- make.unique(names(df)); ord <- names(df) %>% strsplit('\\.') %>% map_df(~list(V1 = .x[1], V2 = as.integer(.x[2]))) %>% invoke(order, ., na.last = FALSE); df <- df[, ord]`

Comment: Or maybe `library(tidyverse); ord <- data_frame(name = names(df)) %>% separate(name, c('var', 'suf'), convert = TRUE, fill = 'right') %>% invoke(order, .)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to approach this,

```
y <- c('ALL', 'ALL.1', 'ALL.2', 'AML.1', 'AML.2', 'ALL.10')

y[order(gsub('\\.\\d+', '', y))]
#[1] "ALL"    "ALL.1"  "ALL.2"  "ALL.10" "AML.1"  "AML.2" 

#or to use it in a data frame,
df[,order(gsub('\\.\\d+', '', names(df))))]
```

Additionally you can use `mixedorder` from `gtools` package but you will have to replace the `.` from the suffix so it won't treat it as decimal (meaning .10 < .2 and not 10 > 2), i.e.

```
library(gtools)

#with the . in suffix
mixedsort(y)
#[1] "ALL.1"  "ALL.10" "ALL.2"  "ALL"    "AML.1"  "AML.2" 

#without the . in suffix
mixedsort(gsub('\\.', '_', y))
#[1] "ALL"    "ALL_1"  "ALL_2"  "ALL_10" "AML_1"  "AML_2" 

#or use it on the data frame
df[,mixedorder(gsub('\\.', '_', names (df)]
```

As for your first case, I agree with @alistaire that names NEED to be unique. Use `make.unique` and follow the method above

Comment: This depends on the subscripts being in ascending order. If it's right after `make.unique`, that's true.

Comment: @alistaire I assumed as much as the numeric suffixes in colnames are put there automatically from some operation so they will always be in increasing order

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! @Sotos, you are right, I was trying to make the duplicate column names as unique, that's how I reached scenario 2, but couldn't quite figure out how to reorder.

Comment: Thanks for your input @alistaire, things to keep in mind for future.